# Normal Distribution - Compare 2 proportions of a class' scores

Tags: normal-distribution

> Jane scored   in the 68th percentile on a test, John scored in the 32nd
> percentile. Compare quantity A with quantity B (i.e. Quantity A is
> greater, less or equal to quantity B) given below:
>
> Quantity A: The proportion of the class that received a score **less than** John’s score.
>
> Quantity B: The proportion of the class that scored **equal to** or **greater than** Jane’s score.

My answer was quantity B is greater than quantity A, because B has not only "**greater than**" but also "**equal to**", when A only has "**less than**".

However the correct answer is quantity A is equal to quantity B:

> Percentiles define the proportion of a group that scores below a
> particular benchmark. Since John scored in the 32nd percentile,   by
> definition, 32% of the class scored worse than John.  Quantity A is
> equal to  32%.
> Jane  scored  in  the 68th    percentile, so  68% of  the class   scored  worse   than    she did.    Since
> 100   –   68  =   32, 32% of  the class   scored  equal   to  or  greater than    Jane.   Quantity    B   is  also
> equal to  32%.

Thus am I wrong? Please help me understand it, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These test scores are assumed to (approximately) follow a continuous distribution, so $P(T=t)=0$ for some test score $t$. In particular, this means $P(T>t_{0.68})=P(T\ge t_{0.68})=1-0.68=0.32$.